# Automatic PHP scripts

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a php/mysql question:

I am designing a website that takes xml feeds and puts them into a mysql table. From that table, I want mysql to take this new information and perform a series of calculations which then changes fields in another part of the database. This newly updated information is then displayed on the website.

I understand how to:

- convert from xml to php
- place these variables into mysql
- calculate the new info (in theory with php)

What I don't get is:
where do I put the php script that tells mysql to do the calculations and what the calculations actually are.

Does it just go in a php file on the database that gets called by a cron job? I have no idea how to do linux commands though I suppose I could learn if needed. Is there any other way to simply put a script on a server and have it called every hour or so and it checks to see if any new tables have been added and if so, it does the calculations?

Comment: I think the solution you mention is best; cron is the easiest way to have a script executed periodically.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a cronjob is what you're looking for. Depending on your server OS flavor (I'm assuming linux), creating one is fairly easy. On a Debian system, you'd put your script file in `/etc/cron.hourly/` and it would be run once every hour.

To create a php script that can be run from the command line, follow this format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
  // do stuff...
?>
```

And don't forget to `chmod +x` the script.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to schedule a job, without using a cron, you could theoretically set up one of your pages to issue an AJAX request.

AJAX call fired on document ready:

```
$.get("my-script.php");
```

Top of myscript.php:

```
$desiredUpdateInteval = 3600; #seconds
    $dbLastUpdatedQuery = mysql_query("SELECT UPDATE_TIME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '*database_name*' AND TABLE_NAME = '*table_name*'");
    $dbLastUpdated      = strtotime(mysql_result($dbLastUpdatedQuery,0,0));

    if((time() - $dbLastUpdated) > $desiredUpdateInterval){
    /* do something */
    }
```

You should note that there's a lot of overhead with this method, as your database is going to get pinged on each page visit.

Comment: +1 very good approach in part II (`UPDATE_TIME FROM information_schema.tables`) !! 
I just wouldn't like to have the timing controlled by user activity, when the php call is placed in the page.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "a website that *takes* XML"?
If xml is taken by a php script of your own, then you should place your re-calculation-call there ... if there is new XML saved to DB. Otherwise you know, that no calculation is needed.

plcae a timestamp attribute "last_updated" in your calculation-results-table, update it if new xml arrived and check on `now() > last_updated + 3600`, to check if an hour is exceeded.

--> PHP pseudo-cronjob...

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple choices here. If you want to keep things in the db then you can look at using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html). Trigger will allow you to do things when something like an update/insert takes place. So in your scenario, when the xml is feed into your db, you can trigger some action to perform calculations without having a cron job call a php file to do the same.

The other option is to do a cron job that calls a php file that does the calculations for you if something has changed. You would have to start a crontab (some examples [here](http://clickmojo.com/code/cron-tutorial.html) - search for php) that calls a php file (you should be able to place the file anywhere you like that you have access too, I would keep it in the site folder but outside of public access unless you want to manually call it by going to a url) every x hours depending on your needs. If you do this, you create a new php file which only needs to check the db for changes, maybe by getting the last id of a table and compare it to the previous id that you saved in a file on the file system. If there is a change, do all the required computations and updates and then it's done until it gets called again later.

Answer (score 0):

`What I don't get is: where do I put the php script that tells mysql to do the calculations and what the calculations actually are.`

Automatic = Cron. Because without it, someone need to execute the script either via browser or CLI.

Now, assume you already have a php script to do the task, and assume you have a ssh access to your server, to set up a cron task you just need to execute (from your bash)

```
crontab -e
```

then set up a cron task (assume for every one hour)

```
*/60 * * * * /path/to/your/php/script.php
```

If you dont have a ssh access, and using cPanel, [see How To using Cron in cPanel](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/cron_jobs.htm)